# How to get only part of a string from a DIV using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="faddress">
    1 myroad valley<br>beverly, VT&nbsp;54803-0989<br>(435) 425-9090 <br><br>
    <a href="someline.html" target="_blank" title="RBP">RBP</a>
    <br><span>(435) 425-9090 </span>
    <div class="mE">1 myroad valley&nbsp;beverly, VT&nbsp;54803-0989</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get only `1 myroad valley` and I used the following JS:

```
var vAdd = $(".mE").text();
var vArr = vAdd.split("&nbsp;");
console.log(vArr[0]);
```

I keep getting the following: `1 myroad valley beverly, VT 54803-0989`

How can I modify the code to get the desired result.

Comment: Why you didnt use substring ?

Comment: Have a look at the value of `vAdd` at runtime. Then it should be easy to find the right split character.

Comment: use html() instead of text()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.html` instead of `.text`:

```
var vAdd = $(".mE").html();
var vArr = vAdd.split("&nbsp;");
alert(vArr[0]);
```

`.text` function get only text and ignore HTML. That's why `.text` not getting `&nbsp;` and you are getting full text.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0m8Lce4c/)**.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge My pleasure to help you. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `html` method instead of the `text` and your code will work.

```
> $(".mE").html();
> "1 myroad valley&nbsp;beverly, VT&nbsp;54803-0989"
> $(".mE").text();
> "1 myroad valley beverly, VT 54803-0989"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript only solution,No need jQuery

```
var vAdd = document.getElementsByClassName('mE')[0].innerHTML;
var vArr = vAdd.split("&nbsp;");
console.log(vArr[0]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hxgz45dc/)